# Как выбрать из базы слова с учетом возможной ошибки при вводе?

Tags: mysql

Допустим пользователь вводит слово "годзилла" - выводится строка. А когда пишешь "годзила" с одной л, то ничего не выводится.
Мой запрос выглядит вот так: SELECT * FROM lists WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$word."')"

Answer (score 0):

сделайте в базе функцию сравнения, например через [редакционное расстояние](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). И выводите слова, отличающиеся не более чем на N букв.

```
select * from lists where wordDistance(word, "enteredWord") < LENGTH(word) * 0.2
```

Comment: да он опухнет сравнивать введённое слово с каждым словом в базе

Comment: На паре тысяч слов это миллисекунды. Если больше - можно добавить дополнительные фильтры. Например, маска по наличию букв

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про алгоритмы нечёткого поиска. Тема обширная. Есть короткие обзоры каждого из возможных подходов. Мне в своё время помогли n-граммы длиной в 3 символа. Про них можно почитать, например, тут [Нечёткий поиск в тексте и словаре](https://habr.com/ru/post/114997/).

Суть в следующем. Делите слово на кусочки длиной 3 буквы. Начиная с первой, со второй и т.д. до третьей с конца. Для каждого слова получается набор таких n-грамм. Храните их в базе. Теперь, если в базе не удалось найти искомое слово от пользователя, разделите его тоже на n-граммы и поищите такое слово в базе, в котором совпадений по n-граммам больше всего. Скорее всего это и будет слово без опечатки.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов: делать запрос во время ввода пользователем и показывать ему подходящие варианты.

В базу запрос будет следующий:

```sql
SELECT * FROM lists WHERE title LIKE "$word%"
```